# How to make geocode request without callback in bing maps version 7?

Tags: maps, geocoding, bing-maps

Is it possible to make geocode request without specify callback function like it was in 6.2 version? I need to receive location data in function from which was executed geocode request.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're refering to the current JSONP interface. Well, assuming that you're using jQuery you can easily work with the callback in the scope of the call.

Example:

```
var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?" + 
    "YOUR_SEARCH_QUERY" + "&output=json&key=" + "YOUR_BINGMAPSKEY";

$.ajax({
    url: geocodeRequest,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        //handle error as you please
    },
    success: function(data, textstatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

        //handle result in the array 'data.resourceSets'
    }
});
```

My geocoding URL may differ from yours. There are specific URLs for specific countries.